# How to make new file inherit permission?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cs50

I am using CS50 appliance(Ubuntu).
My php function adds images in the imgs folder of public.
But each time after addition I have to manually change the permission of the newly added file for it to be view-able in my webpage.
Is there any way for me to set the default permission of any file being added to the folder imgs as 644?

Comment: Why are you still using _CS50 appliance_? You can easily use the CS50 Cloud9 IDE available online.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod 777 yourFloderName/*
```

Comment: That didn't help.